# How to determine if an ImageView is visible in CollapsingToolbar?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar layout that looks like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

       <include layout="@layout/circle_image_view"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

where `circle_image_view` is

```
<com.example.ui.CircularParseImageView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iv_circular_backdrop"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_pic"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

This is just a standard image view with a circular mask.  When the the collapsing toolbar is expanded, the circular Image view is visible and shows like:

[image: Expanded view]

When collapsed, the image view is no longer visible as follows:

[image: Collapsed view]

However it seems like the visibility of the image view is still set to Visible even in the collapsed state.  When the user presses the back button, I need to determine whether the image is visible or not to perform a shared element transition animation.  **How can I determine if the image is currently visible or not within the collapsing toolbar?**

What I have tried:

`getVisibility()`  remains unchanged

`isOpaque()` remains unchanged

`getImageAlpha()` remains unchanged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using [CollapsingToolbarLayout#getContentScrim()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#getContentScrim()) which according to documentation:

> Returns the drawable which is used for the foreground scrim.

Seems like the image view is always visible but the foreground scrim hides it so using the `alpha` property `getContentScrim().getAlpha()` you can determine whether the image is visible or not.

Answer (score 3):

this can be achieved using your own implementation of a OnOffsetChangedListener.

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
                // Collapsed
            } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
                // Expanded
            } else {
                // Somewhere in between
            }
        }
    }););
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                boolean isContentHide = mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getScrimVisibleHeightTrigger() + Math.abs(verticalOffset) > mCollapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!